# An Ant BuildException has occured

Tags: maven, ant

Try to do mvn clean install for some project.
In the end the build failed with this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.6:run (default)
on project abc-sm-wsdl: An Ant BuildException has occured:
The following error occurred while executing this line:

[ERROR] C:\ABC\wsdl\build-aif.xml:67:
The following error occurred while executing this line:

[ERROR] C:\ABC\wsdl\build-aif.xml:125: Java returned: 1
```

Try to googling but ineffectually.
Maybe somebody know hot to resolve it.

Comment: Correct, and pointing out the obvious the ANT code on lines 67 + 125 of your build file "C:\ABC\wsdl\build-aif.xml" is where to locate the problem. From our perspective it could be anything. Now since there is "WSDL" in the directory name.. that suggests this might be a generated ANT script? If so you're very brave to be mixing ANT file generation with a Maven build! The problem I'm sure is solveable, but not without more information.